# When to use HTTP Request and when to use Illuminate Support Facades Request in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have been using laravel so far but sometimes I am so confused about choosing correct Request listed bellow.

```
use Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
```

I have created a test method to my corresponding Route & Controller like bellow.

```
public function test()
{
    dd(Request::all());
}
```

If I choose `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;` or `use Request;` it work's fine and get empty array.

But When I choose use `Illuminate\Http\Request;`

I get error message saying `Request::all()` should not be called statically. So, it arises two question in my mind.

1. What's the difference among them ?
2. When to use Http Request or Illuminate Support Facades Request. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

Try This

Comment: It would work but it does not reply the question.

Comment: I know that works too. Please explain what's the difference between http request and illuminate support facades request.